# Retrieving message from word document onto outlook

Tags: vba, excel

I need to send emails out to various people, I already have a **list of people to send and I wanted to retrieve the body message from another file titled "Message"**.

So the body message would be as follows:

1. **(Greeting) (First Name)** - greetings and first name are in two separate columns in the excel spreadsheet.
2. **(Message)** - to be taken from a word document

I have the below mentioned code :

```
Sub newmethod()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Email As String, Subj As String, MailBody As String, Greetings As String, MailEnd As String, MailRemarks As String, Firmname As String, TradeConfo As String

Dim MailDate As String
Dim Msg As String, URL As String
Dim r As Integer, x As Double
Dim AvgPrice As Double
Dim attachment As String, subjectline As String
Dim lastRow As Integer

lastRow = Sheets("Yes Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow
    attachment = Sheets("Yes Sheet").Cells(i, 6).Value
    EmailTo = Sheets("Yes Sheet").Cells(i, 5).Value
    subjectline = Sheets("Yes Sheet").Cells(i, 7).Value

' Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
' Working in Office 2000-2010
Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
'Only the visible cells in the selection
Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'You can also use a range if you want
'Set rng =         Sheets("YourSheet").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

'If rng Is Nothing Then
'    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
'           vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
'    Exit Sub
'End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .to = EmailTo
    .Subject = subjectline
    .Attachments.Add (attachment)
    .Display   
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Next i

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Would anyone be able to help me with this?

Many Thanks!

Comment: What is your problem on this? An error (which one, on which line?), ... ?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you (I clean your code a bit and pointed where you should made the changes for your own precise purpose) :

```
Sub newmethod()

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Dim Email As String, _
    Subj As String, _
    MailBody As String, _
    Greetings As String, _
    MailEnd As String, _
    MailRemarks As String, _
    FirmName As String, _
    TradeConfo As String, _
    MailDate As String, _
    Msg As String, _
    URL As String, _
    r As Integer, _
    x As Double, _
    AvgPrice As Double, _
    attachment As String, _
    subjectline As String, _
    lastRow As Integer, _
    rng As Range, _
    OutApp As Outlook.Application, _
    OutMail As Outlook.MailItem, _
    PathToWordFile As String, _
    oWord As Word.Application, _
    oDoc As Word.Document, _
    BodyFromWord As String

'--------------- change path here ---------------
PathToWordFile = "H:/Test/Message.docx"
'------------------------------------------------
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(PathToWordFile)
    BodyFromWord = oDoc.Content.Text
oDoc.Close
oWord.Quit
Set oWord = Nothing
Set oDoc = Nothing


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

lastRow = Sheets("Yes Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastRow
    attachment = Sheets("Yes Sheet").Cells(i, 6).Value
    EmailTo = Sheets("Yes Sheet").Cells(i, 5).Value
    subjectline = Sheets("Yes Sheet").Cells(i, 7).Value

    '--------------- change path here ---------------
    Greeting = Sheets("Yes Sheet").Cells(i, 2).Value
    FirmName = Sheets("Yes Sheet").Cells(i, 1).Value
    '------------------------------------------------

    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = EmailTo
        .Subject = subjectline
        .Body = Greeting & FirmName & "," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & BodyFromWord
        .Attachments.Add (attachment)
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i

DoEvents

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```